# ruby get array variable index value inside array

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, indexing

is there a way to get a value of index from arrays?

```
class Datadump
 def ddlist()
     @tobethrown = [
        sofa = ["red", "blue", "striped"],
        toys = ["figures", "robots", "comics"]
        ]
 end
 def dddig(chkdump)
     #check index value of array from string
     #I expect [1][2]
 end
end

dumpoop = Datadump.new
dumpoop.ddlist()
dumpoop.dddig("comics")
```

I can get the value using tobethrown.index() if the contens is only ["sofa", "toys"] but not them as variables. I am new in ruby, so forgive me if it's kind of noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@tobethrown.each.with_index do |a, i| 
  j = a.index(chkdump) 
  return [i, j] if j
end
```

Comment: Lukav, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark symbol if it answers your question.